# Installing ggplot2 causes error "namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.6 is being loaded, but >= 0.3.8 is required")

Tags: r, ggplot2

I installed ggplot2 by using

```r
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

But the code `library(ggplot2)` led to the error message

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.6 is being loaded, but >= 0.3.8 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.0.5"
```

How do address this issue?

Comment: What version of `R` are you running? Restart R. Try updating vctrs with `install.packages("vctrs")`. If you have an `.Rprofile` file that loads packages at startup, make sure to temporarily disable that.

Comment: RStudio Desktop 1.4.1106. install.packages("vctrs") worked. Thanks for your help!